# Is it possible to use an extension in a template like a plugin?

Tags: templates, php, extension

I built an extension which works fine and I'm trying to make it work in my template but I don't know how to do and actually, I don't even know if it could work.

My code looks like:

```
class Easypost_extension_ext

{

    public $name        = 'Easypost extensions';
    public $version     = '1.0.0';
    public $description = 'Display shipment only if there is a product to send';
    public $docs_url    = 'https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/';
    public $settings_exist = 'n';
    public $settings    = array();
    private $EE;
    private $apikey;
```

My function is called check_shipping and I'm trying to call it in my template in this way:

```
<select class="form-control" id="easypost" name="easypost">
    {exp:easypost_extention:check_shipping}
    <option value="">
        {service}
        {days}
        {rate}
        {currency}
        {rateid}
    </option>
    {/exp:easypost_extention:check_shipping}
</select>
```

But I receive an error in my template. Is there any way to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ext to call in template as plugin. You must have to create `mod.easypost_extention.php` file for that. Use this code inside that file.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Easypost_extension
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    function check_shipping()
    {

        $tagdata    = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
        $tagparams  = ee()->TMPL->tagparams;

        // Some code


        return ee()->TMPL->parse_variables_row($tagdata, $myArrayToParse);
    }
}
```

You can gain more information from here. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between tagdata and tagparams?

Comment: you will get everything written between `{exp:your:plugin} {/exp:your:plugin}` in tagdata. In tagparams you will get array of each and every parameters you passed in your loop: `{exp:plugin data="abc" entry="12" etc.}`